# RequireJS e Carregamento de páginas via ajax

Tags: requirejs

Olá, alguém tem algum exemplo de uso do requirejs com páginas que foram carregadas via ajax.

Minha dúvida é como organizar o código para que quando a página for recarregada via ajax os elementos sejam manipulados por códigos jquery. Sem o requirejs quando carrego uma página via ajax (jquery) no oncomplete eu chamo uma função para manipular a página. Porém, tem os jquery que precisam ser carregados.

Estou querendo utilizar o requirejs para organizar o código de forma eficiente.